# Query that SELECTs a list of distinct strings with the highest count

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

- I have a table that has only 3 columns - `uid/timestamp/tag`
- In each row the tag column stores a single word (`string`)

I'd like to query the table to select the top 10 distinct tags that are mentioned the most in order.

If possible I'd also like to add a count to each row that represents how many times the tag that row represents was mentioned.

I know this has to be possible, but I'm drawing a blank as to how to go about it. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) which is an *aggregate function* and group them by `TAG`. The result is then order through the count of each tag in descending order.

```
SELECT  tag, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY tag
ORDER   BY totalCount DESC
LIMIT   10
```